# Overwriting a row in a two dimensional arraylist

Tags: java

I have a 2D arraylist containing 4 cols. I want to add a 5 th column to this arraylist.
the fourth col is a set of values based on which the result is to be added as the 5th column.
If 1st row has 4th element as 0 then the fifth column will have a result string "Failure"

Is it ok to use a 1D arraylist to get all the elements of the 2D arraylist and add the 5th element to it and then overwrite the 2D with the 1D arraylist items 
OR
Is there a way we can directly append to the 2D arraylist using the index() and indexOF()?

Will appreciate it if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: Could you add some code to show exactly how your objects are structured?

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList> Resultarray=new ArrayList<ArrayList();ArrayList<String> Rarray=new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<Resultarray.size();i++){lastflag=0;index=0;
for(int j=0;j<=5;j++){ 
if((i!=0)&&(j==4)){
compvalue=Double.parseDouble(Resultarray.get(i).get(j).toString());
if((compvalue>=amin)&&(compvalue<=amax)){
mtype="AutoMatch";}
else
mtype="NoMatch";}
if((i!=0)&&(j==5)){
concat=concat+mtype;lastflag=1;}if(lastflag==0)
concat=concat+(Resultarray.get(i).get(j).toString())+delim;}}Rarray.add(concat);

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support first-class multi-dimensional arrays.  A two dimensional array is an 'array of arrays'.  Java also does not support resizing of arrays.

Assuming you've already got data in your String[][] table:

```
String[][] table = /* init from somewhere */;

for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
   String[] row = table[i];
   assert (row.length == 4);
   String[] newRow = Arrays.copyOf(row, 5);
   assert (newRow.length == 5);
   newRow[4] = "Failure";
   table[i] = newRow;
}
```

That's approximately how you'd handle adding a column.
Notice that Arrays.copyOf() is much better than copying the array's contents 'by hand'.

(note: when you run this sample, use the -ea flag to the JVM so that the assertions fire)

Comment: Could you mention the same with arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use ArrayList#add

```
for(ArrayList<Object> a: in aa){
    a.add(a.get(3) == 0 ? "failure" : "success")
}
```

Comment: I had tried using the add but all it does is append to the already existing row. I want to rewrite the entire row of my 2D  arraylist